# Prevent only undefined values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In mongoose I can set `required: true` to block ... falsey? values.

But I want to allow `''`, `[]`, `0`, `null`, and only block `undefined`.

How can I do this?

```
const MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

I want to allow `document.name` to be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent `undefined`, while still allowing `null` you can just use a custom validator:

```
const MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: v => v !== undefined,
      message: 'name is required',
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: If the type was `[String]` I'd want to allow `[]`, if the type is `String` I'd want to allow `''` etc. (I don't want a `Mixed` type)

Comment: doesn't the default `required` validator provide much more info than this custom validator when it errors?

Comment: @minseong You can add a message to it. If you prefer to use the default validator you can, but it doesn't allow empty strings or null.

Comment: do you know what the default validator looks like? So I can just copy every aspect of it except the checking function

Comment: My answer basically is copying every aspect of it. It's defined here: It's defined here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/2623702f865888be65c50dc6ce8a7c906220ece5/lib/schematype.js#L644, which just sets a default message if you didn't provide one and uses `this.requiredValidator` which calls checkRequired for the given type. For a string it's `checkRequired` does this: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/3b345be86763b6c8580e5a3748b046b42b5e4227/lib/schema/string.js#L398 (the `&& value.length` ensures that the string is non-empty).

Comment: How would I re-write `required` to use the `validate:` syntax in my schema? So that all behaviour is identical?

Comment: @minseong `validate: { validator: v => v !== undefined, message: 'name is required', }`, like my answer says. It behave identically, except it doesn't treat `null` or the empty string as invalid, which I think is what you really want.

Comment: I have about a hundred keys in my schema that will need to use this custom validator. Is there a way I can write the schema to avoid repetition of the large section that your `validate:` takes up?

Comment: You could store the object `{ validator: v => v !== undefined, message: 'must be defined' }` in a variable called `isDefined` and then use `validate: isDefined` everywhere. If you want you could even make a module that just contains that and maybe some other custom validators and then import that module into each of the files that your schema are defined in.

Comment: I don't think it does behave identically to `required` because I think `required` customises the error message based on the field

Comment: @minseong Nope, it just uses the default message for required always, which is `'Path \`{PATH}\` is required.'` You can change the message to that if you want, but behaviour otherwise is the same.